# SEO and dynamic structured data (microdata)

Tags: seo, microdata, structured-data, json-ld

I'm wanting to have a very limited amount of structured data (ideally microdata)  added using javascript, especially using the document's `lastModified` property. It seems rather bizarre and counter-intuative to have to update the structured data for each small edit on a webpage.

According to [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68975/structured-data-for-dynamic-pages-and-webmaster-tools) and [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org) the best way to do this is to use JSON-LD rather than microdata. I've looked at the JSON-LD documentation and examples but as far as I am unable to find an example of this. How do I do this?

The page currently has the javascript that sets the contents (innerHTML) of `<span id="moddate"></span>` to the `lastModified` date.

This is the JSON-LD I have so far, how do I made `modifiedDate` work via javascript?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "WebPage",
"author": "http://plus.google.com/12345678",
"breadcrumb": "Articles > MedicalArticle > Psychology",
"datePublished": "2014-05-01",
"dateModified": "2015-05-01",  
}
</script>
```

The is already existing microdata for the `WebPage` schema including author and additional fields.

Comment: Is your question **how to modify the value of a JSON-LD property with JavaScript**? If yes, this probably belongs to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this involved a code snippet and needs *jquery* plus *moment.js* to set the citation_online_data meta tag to the current date.

Add to the `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var dateModified = moment(document.lastModified).format("YYYY/MM/DD"); 
$('head').append( '<meta name="citation_online_date" content="' +  dateModified + '">');

//create JSON-LD for lastModified and citation_online_date
var el = document.createElement('script');  
el.type = 'application/ld+json';  
el.id = 'jsonld';
el.text = JSON.stringify({ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebPage", "url": "http:"+window.location.href, "datePublished": "+dateModified+" }); 
$('body').append(el);
});
</script>
```